# select() system call is CPU consuming

Tags: c, performance, embedded-linux, strace

I wrote an application that accept different remote client and is based `select()` to distribute the job to different handlers. I noticed that on one platform running an ARM926EJ-S and a kernel 2.6.33-rc4, the application uses a lot of CPU! Here is what I could see by running my application for 30 seconds with *strace -c*:

```
% time     seconds  usecs/call     calls    errors syscall
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
 98.47    3.680000      204444        18           select
...
```

However, if I send continuously data to the application from my remote clients, select uses much less CPU!

```
% time     seconds  usecs/call     calls    errors syscall
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
 44.69    0.340278         175      1945           gettimeofday
 40.71    0.310000       25833        12           select
  3.94    0.030000       30000         1           fsync
...
```

I'm wondering if `select()` is implemented with a busy waiting. However, on an older platform, running a MIPS processor and a 2.6.30.10 Linux kernel this problem didn't appear, despite I should cross-compile strace to confirm that ...! And as data are "rarely" sent, I'm mostly in the worst case!

I'm wondering where the problem could come from! C Library? Linux kernel? On the other hand, I'm not sure if writting a multi threaded application will result in better performance because of `pthread`, critical section, ... ?

I read two interesting articles on the Internet:

- [*"Scalable kernel performance for Internet servers under realistic loads"*](http://kdb.snu.ac.kr/~tsangbi/References/network/1998%20Scalable%20kernel%20performance%20for%20internet%20servers%20under%20realistic%20loads.pdf)
- [*"A scalable and explicit event delivery mechanism for UNIX"*](http://static.usenix.org/event/usenix99/full_papers/banga/banga_html/final2.html)

Unfortunately they are pretty old (from '98/'99) I'd like to know if someone else faced that kind of problem or if you had any other suggestion to improve performance or point to the real problem?

**EDIT**:
I noticed that more clients are connected more my application uses CPU, this despite the clients don't send any data! As the most time is spent in select, I though that the select itself that consumes more CPU!
What other free tools could I used under ARM to profile my application and point the problem? Valgrind doesn't work (yet) on ARM9 ...

Comment: What makes you say select consumes a lot of CPU time? The first trace clearly shows that a lot of time is spent in select, yes, but that's what you'd expect to see. The call blocks until there's data to act on.

Answer (score 7):

`strace -c` does not measure CPU time spent but overall time spent in the syscall. See its manpage:

> Count time, calls, and errors for each  system  call and  report  a 
>   summary  on program exit.

So it would actually be bad if you wouldn't have `select` at a high percentage on low load!

You can use `perf` (`linux-tools` package on debian/ubuntu) to measure overall performance, including kernel code.

Comment: Sure, but maybe this comment confused me on the manpage, a little further than your quote: "On Linux, this attempts to show system time (CPU time spent running in the  kernel) independent  of  wall  clock time."

Comment: yes, but since `select` is special in that it blocks until some external event happens, the "attempt" could fail, although I'm not familiar with internals of strace. You would have to look at its source to see how it does this measures CPU time in this case.